# Laravel AJAX dosen't work at all

Tags: ajax, laravel

So, tried more than 10 ways to make a simple ajax form with laravel but none of them works correctly.
Dose any one has a working example that works on last 5.2 laravel framework.

### Thanks

File (routes.php) :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index');
    Route::get('/ajaxsubcat/{id}', 'CategoryController@cats');
});
```

File (CategoryController.php) :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use App\Subcategory;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('index', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }
    public function cats(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $cat_id = $id;
        $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id', '=', $id)->get();
        return Response::json($subcategories);
    }
}
```

File (index.blade.php) :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Categories</title>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Cats & Subs</h1>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ Form::open(['url'=>'', 'files'=>'true']) }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">cats</label>
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="category" name="category">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">subs</label>
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    $('#category').on('change',function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var cat_id = e.target.value;
        //ajax
        $.get('/ajaxsubcat/'+cat_id, function(data){
            //success data
            $('#subcategory').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
                $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and explain the problem.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Did you try to add the csrf token field in your ajax options?

Comment: ajaxsubcat/1 url not found.
and 'Response' class not found :
     return Response::json($subcategories);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add the X-CSRF token to your request. For that, add the following line into your `<head></head>` tag in your html:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And in your ajax request:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '/ajaxsubcat/' + cat_id,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

request.success(function(data) {
    //success data
    $('#subcategory').empty();
    $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
        $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
    });
});
```

Here is the documentation for that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: how about responding 'return Response::json($subcategories);' it dosen't work (Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::json()) ?!

Comment: You don't need to make a Response::json(), Laravel automatically converts it to Json, you only need to make a `return $subcategories`